# How to split the string on a dot and extract all the fields efficiently?

Tags: c++, string, split

I am trying to split my actual `key` on dot and then extract all the fields after splitting it on dot.

My key would look like something this -

```
t26.example.1136580077.colox
```

Currently, I am able to extract only the first field which is `t26` after splitting it on the first dot. Now I am not sure how to extract all the other fields as well using the below code which is more like C.

Below is my code I am using currently to extract the first field from it.

```
if (key)
{
    char* first_dot = strchr(key, '.');
    if (first_dot)
    {
        // cut at the first '.' character
        first_dot[0] = 0;
    }
}

cout << "Fist Key: " << key << endl;
```

After splitting on dot. My first field will be `string` which in this case is `t26`, second field will also be `string` which in this case is `example`, third field will be `uint64_t` which in this case is `1136580077` and fourth field will also be string which in this case is `colox`.

Any thoughts how this can be done efficiently? Using `strtok` is more efficient as compared to `istringstream`?

Comment: Using strtok is more efficient

Comment: @AliKazmi, just curious why is it so?

Comment: strtok is c based function, talking about Split function in C# , it calls strtok on users behalf, so you dont we directly call strtok and save some execution time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

vector<string> spilt(char str[])
{
    vector<string> res;
    char* p;
    char* totken = strtok_s(str, ".", &p);
    while(totken != NULL)
    {
         res.push_back(totken);
         totken = strtok_s(NULL, ".", &p);
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "t26.example.1136580077.colox";
    vector<string> res = spilt(str);
    string field1 = res[0];
    string field2 = res[1];
    uint64_t field3 = atoi(res[2].c_str());
    string field4 = res[3];

    cout<<field1<<" "<<field2<<" "<<field3<<" "<<field4<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Without using while loop is there any way to extract everything so that I can put individual values in its datatype?

Comment: I think you cann't. Mybe you should use some regular expression lib.

Comment: I see.. if we need to use while loop then how to put individual field values in its corresponding datatype as I have shown in my question?

Comment: @TrekkieTechieT-T I have updated my answer, please have a try.

Comment: Thanks. After adding your code and after compiling this is what I am getting `error: âstrtok_sâ was not declared in this scope`. Any idea how to fix these issue?

Comment: @TrekkieTechieT-T `strtok_s` is simply the Windows version of `strtok_r` which is linux version. I think your are in linux, please use `strtok_r`. See http://www.linuxhowtos.org/manpages/3/strtok_r.htm

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41928/discussion-between-trekkietechie-t-t-and-blackmamba)

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that splits the string and qualifies the components of the key. Given your concern for efficiency, use strchr to locate the dots and strncpy to extract the component values where length for strncpy is determined by pointer deltas.

Here's some untested pseudo code:

```
const int MAX_COMP_SIZE = 256;

int count = 0;
const char *p = key;

if (p != NULL) 
{
    char comp[MAX_COMP_SIZE];
    const int CompSize = sizeof(comp)/sizeof(comp[0]);

    while (*p != '\0')
    {
        const char *q = strchr(p, '.');

        if (q != NULL)
        {
            int len = q - p;

            if (len >= CompSize)
                return -1;

            strncpy(comp, p, q-p)[len] = '\0';
        }
        else
        {
            if (strlen(p) >= CompSize)
                return -1;

            strcpy(comp, p);
        }

        // store/verify key components based on index, count
        // implement in separate function
        switch(count)
        {
            case 0: ...
            case 1: ...
            default: return -1;
        }

        count++

        if (q == NULL)
            break;

        q++; // skip dot

        p = q; // setup next

    }

}   

if (count < REQUIRED_KEY_COMPONENTS)
    return -1;
```